# Issue while checking radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to show a red circle with the "!" when the radio buttons are unchecked and to show a green circle when both are checked. After that I use a function to make the button submit or not according to the red/green circle.

I've tried many ways to tangle with the code but it doesn't want to show the green circle when it's checked any idea why ?

PS:

span3 (red circle )

span2 (green circle)

Basically I want to make my form  validation by js not by php ...

HTML:

```html
<label id="labelage">Age:</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="under_13" value="under_13" name="age">
<label for="under_13" class="light">Under 13</label>
<input type="radio" id="over_13" value="over_13" name="age">
<label for="over_13" class="light">13 or Older</label>
<div class="break"></div>

<div id="borderlabel">

  <label id="labelage1">Gender:</label>
  <input type="radio" id="male" value="male" name="gender">
  <label for="male" class="light1">Male</label>

  <input type="radio" id="female" value="female" name="gender">
  <label for="female" class="light1">Female</label>

</div>
....
<button type="submit" id="signupb" name="register">Sign up
  <div class="span3">!</div>
  <div class="span2">✔</div>
</button>
```

JavaScript

```
$(".span1").hide();
$(".span2").hide();
$(".span3").hide();


function submit() {
  if (!$('#male').is(':checked') || !$('#female').is(':checked')) {
    $(".span3").show();
  } else {
    if (!$('#under_13').is(':checked') || !$('#over_13').is(':checked')) {
      $(".span3").show();
    } else {
      $(".span2").show();
    }
  }
}

$("#signupb").on("mouseover", submit);
```

Comment: Here's a phrase I've heard echoed time and time again: "Make sure to validate on server side, no matter what!"  As well as javascript validation, you're leaving it very vulnerable to attacks without server-side validation (PHP)

Comment: Do you have it all in a `form` tag?

Comment: The logic would likely be `if (!$('#male').is(':checked') && !$('#female').is(':checked'))`

Comment: Thank you for your advice , I'll bear that in mind , I will learn more about php in the future right now I am working on this js , I am currently learning php :)

Comment: Yeah it's all rapped in a form and it submits to the database , I've forgot about the radio buttons so now I am here ... @AhmadBaktashHayeri

Comment: How do you make the check mark, what is the ASCII or alt code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your logic is off
2. Have the radio clicks also update the !
3. Do not call something `submit`
4. Cancel the submission if clicking anyway

Try this:

```js
function checkRad() {
  var ok = ($('#male').is(':checked') || $('#female').is(':checked')) && 
              ($('#under_13').is(':checked') || $('#over_13').is(':checked'))
  $(".span3").toggle(!ok);
  $(".span2").toggle(ok);
  return ok;
}

$(function() {
  $(".span1").hide();
  $(".span2").hide();
  $(".span3").hide();
  $("#signupb").on("mouseover", checkRad)
  .on("click", function(e) {
     if (!checkRad()) e.preventDefault();
  })

  $("input[type=radio]").on("click", function() {
    checkRad();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="labelage">Age:</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="under_13" value="under_13" name="age">
<label for="under_13" class="light">Under 13</label>
<input type="radio" id="over_13" value="over_13" name="age">
<label for="over_13" class="light">13 or Older</label>
<div class="break"></div>

<div id="borderlabel">

  <label id="labelage1">Gender:</label>
  <input type="radio" id="male" value="male" name="gender">
  <label for="male" class="light1">Male</label>

  <input type="radio" id="female" value="female" name="gender">
  <label for="female" class="light1">Female</label>

</div>
....
<button type="submit" id="signupb" name="register">Sign up
  <div class="span3">!</div>
  <div class="span2">✔</div>
</button>
```

Comment: I just added the click too so the button updates when the user clicks the radios

Comment: Thanks again for eveything :)

Comment: I looked again, reversed the logic and prevent the submit button to be clicked if error

Answer (score 0):

- I would recommend using [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin instead
- It's bad practice to assign IDs to every input element, makes code harder to maintain. Consider accessing elements by `name` attribute.
- Consider adding server-side validation as well against browser errors/malicious users.

---

Change your `submit()` function to:

```
function validateForm() {
    $(".span2").hide();
    $(".span3").hide();

    var isError = false;
    if (!$('#male').is(':checked') && !$('#female').is(':checked')) {
        isError = true
    } else if (!$('#under_13').is(':checked') && !$('#over_13').is(':checked')) {
        isError = true;
    }

    if(isError){
        $(".span3").show();
    } else {
        $(".span2").show();
    }
}

$("#signupb").on("mouseover", validateForm);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/urLmw0p3/1/)